# Convert Python selenium code to work faster

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Below code is working fine but it is taking too much time. Is there any way i can do this faster? I tried BeautifulSoup but was unable to fetch the nested table entry data. Can anyone help how this can be done in faster way?

```
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument("headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
browser.get(my_url)
table = browser.find_element_by_id("testModuleViewerGrid")
tbody = table.find_element_by_tag_name("tbody")
rows = tbody.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")  # get all of the rows in the table

for row in rows:
    module_name = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[0]
    module_status = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2]
    module_status_value = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "span")[0]
    test_name.append((module_name.text))
    test_status.append((module_status_value.text))
```

No error in this code but it is taking too much time to scrape the data

Comment: If the page does not have dynamic javascript, then beautifulsoup should work, and much faster.

Comment: Can you send the link to `my_url` please? Otherwise, I'm just guessing what might or might not work

Comment: And, counterpoint to @JohnGordon, if it DOES have dynamic content, you're limited by the loading speed of the page elements and there's not much you can do to help with that

Comment: I cannot share the url but it consist of table and entries in table are dynamic. Hope this will help

Comment: How many rows are in `rows`?

Comment: more than 800 rows